# Null space of the sum of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If we have two square matrices A and B then can we claim that $N(A + B)\supset N(A) $ and $N(A + B)\supset N(B)$,  respectively ? I have this doubt. Could anybody help me with this? I would be very much thankful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $\ker (A+B) = \{0\}$, $\ker A = \operatorname{sp} \{ e_1 \}$, $\ker B = \operatorname{sp} \{ e_2 \}$.

Clearly, neither $\ker A$ nor $\ker B$ are contained in $\ker (A+B)$.

Answer (score 7):

As the other answers have indicated, your assertions are not true. However, a moment's thought does reveal that we can salvage a partial result:

$$N(A+B) \supseteq N(A)\cap N(B)$$

which effectively rests on the fact that $0 + 0 = 0$ in any vector space.

---

As per request, a proof of the above. We are asserting that $v \in N(A) \cap N(B)$ implies $v \in N(A+B)$. Now suppose that the premise holds, i.e. $v \in N(A)\cap N(B)$:

$$\begin{align*}(A+B)v &= Av + Bv & & \text{by definition of $(A+B)v$} \\
&= 0 + 0 & & \text{since $v \in N(A)$ and $v \in N(B)$} \\ &= 0\end{align*}$$

hence $v \in N(A+B)$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: farin Thanks for your reply. Could you give me proof of your assertion? It would be very helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: @ Lord farin Thanks for your answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

two systems (A+B)x=0 and Ax=0 do not have same answer always!

so $N(A + B)\supset N(A)
$ is not always correct!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $A$ be any non-zero matrix and let $B$ be the zero matrix (and vice versa).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I am taking both $A$ and $B$ as a non zero matrix.

Comment: That's not what I recommended in my answer. Either let $A$ be non-zero and let $B$ be zero, **or** let $A$ be zero and let $B$ be non-zero. What happens in either case? (What is the null space of the zero matrix?)

Comment: @Zevv If B is null matrix then every vector in the corresponding space will be null space of B. Perhaps I am not able to get your hint :(.

Comment: That's correct; every vector is in the null space of the zero matrix. Now consider this: *is it possible for every vector to be in the null space of a non-zero matrix*?